# IIS url redirect rule in web.config

Tags: iis, redirect

I want to write a rule for a redirect in my web.config.

I want to redirect urls like...

http://www.example.net/profile/username

to...

http://www.example.net/#/profile/username

I have added the below run but it doesn't seem to work. What is the best way to do this?

```
  <rule name="Redirect to hashed profile" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" pattern="^.net/profile/*"/>
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/#/{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what's going on and how you fix it.

```
pattern="^.net/profile/*"
```

The `^` anchors the text to the beginning of your HTTP_HOST which is `www.example.com`  So `^.net` means your URL must start with any 1 character `.` and then the word `net`.  I'm going to assume you meant you wanted to match the literal `.`, in order to do that you have to escape it as `\.`

You also have to escape the `/` to `\/` and also `*` at the end of a slash just means match unlimited slashes, but you want it to match any character after the slash unlimited times, so it's `.*`

So let's rewrite that pattern as we can't use the `^` because your website don't start with `.net`

```
pattern="\.net\/profile\/.*"
```

That will give you this..

```
  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" pattern="\.net\/profile\/.*">
```

But do you really need the {HTTP_HOST}? It really depends if this is a global rule, if it's not a global rule, and it's at the application level. Then you don't need it.

Now you can add back in the `^` to anchor the word `profile` to the first part of the REQUEST_URI like this.

```
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" pattern="^profile\/.*">
```